# Get nested parent HREF node without Jquery

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a simple Firefox plugin and I'm trying to get the parent HREF node of a IMG in those cases where nodes are nested as:

```
<a href="http://somesite.com">
     <div id="some_div">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
     </div>
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://somesite.com">
     <div id="some_div">
           <span class="some_class">    
               <img src="image.jpg" />
           </span>
     </div>
</a>
```

With Firefox SDK I can get the IMG SRC link and its parent node:

```
var href = node.parentNode.href;
```

but not if the HREF node some levels above.

Any help to write some pure Javascript code to "climb" up the DOM tree until it reaches the A HREF node, starting from the IMG SRC, will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

By using Touffy answer below this is the code up to now:

```
self.on("click", function (node, data) {
    if (node.nodeName == "A") { 
        var link = node.href; 
    }
    if (node.nodeName == "IMG") {
        var imgsrc = node.src;
        var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        var href = nearestAncestorHref(nodes[0]);
    }
    var s = link +  " " + imgsrc + " " + href;
    self.postMessage(s);
});

function nearestAncestorHref(node){
    while(node && !node.href) node=node.parentNode
    return node && node.href
}
```

but console.log returns the absolute first A HREF it founds in whole page. For example I tried on a random image on bbc.com and the function returned http://www.bbc.com and not the link of the image I clicked on.

Why I'm separating A HREF and IMG SRC when I could get both using node.href and node.src? Because I'm not able to get from Firefox SDK both values, but only one at a time.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` will always return the first image on the whole page, so of course the nearest ancestor href is likely to be on one of the first link on the page as well. Why don't you use the `node` itself? forgot to remove some old code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the href of the nearest ancestor that has an href, or `null` if it reaches the `<HTML>` root without finding anything.

```
function nearestAncestorHref(node){
  while(node && !node.href) node=node.parentNode
  return node && node.href
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at the original post. I used your code but without success.

Comment: I looked. I went to bbc.com like you said in your post, and tried it with `node=document.querySelector(".hero2 img")`. It works.

Comment: the question is, why are you using `document.getElementsByTagName('img')` in your code and using the first item all the time? that will always return the first image on the page.

Comment: My code works fine. It's just that for some reason (or probably no reason) your code gets a reference to the very first image on the page and passes that to my function instead of the original node that you put the 'click' listener on.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHref(node) {
    if(node.href != null) {
        return node.href;
    } else {
        if(node.parentNode != null) {
             return getHref(node.parentNode);  
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qy95vzv/

Answer (score -2):

```
 var href = document.getElementById('some_div').parentNode;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ox8r377v/